# Setting a titlebar instead of actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, titlebar

I followed Xamarin's "Replacing the action bar" tutorial for setting titlebar instead of actionbar , i get the following error: [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02WN7.png)
What should i do for this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Another error message i get for same code is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5dziBRNZg4XRzROeFA5SVBPeWc/view?usp=sharing This should be an easy question for you advanced guys.

Comment: Could you post your code and errors as a text, not as images?

Comment: I could write here then. Sorry for not having order of codes.. I do no know how to write with formatting. Pictures may help better. Here is the error i get: "Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: This activity already has an actionbar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set android:windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead."

Comment: ` using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ToolbarFun
{
    [Activity(Label = "ToolbarFun", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main)


            var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetActionBar(toolbar);
            ActionBar.Title = "My Toolbar"; `

Comment: `toolbar.setTitle="My toolbar"` try this one.

Comment: That's true, i do not use actionbar anymore but the error seemed to be occured in previous line of code: setActionBar(toolbar);    :(